# slow build librealsense libusb

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, realsense

When I start my program it takes very long to build, like 3.5 minutes.
I get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: libusb (ExternalProjectTargets\libusb\libusb), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
    1>Performing update step for 'libusb'
    2>Performing configuration step for 'libusb'
    3>Performing building step for 'libusb'
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on and how I can speed up the building? This problem is only with the wrapper from librealsense

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered a similar problem. When compiling librealsense and executing cmake, it will detect the network connection. If there is a network connection, it will download some files such as libusb. When you disconnect the network, there may not be the problem you asked.